# Express CORS middleware to handle both preflight and normal requests

Tags: javascript, express, cors, middleware

I have CORS globally configured like this, to handle credentials:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://example.com', credentials: true }))
```

But on certain routes, I need to allow options requests, so following the documentation, I'm doing something like this:

```
router.options('/someroute', cors())
router.get('/someroute', cors(), someOtherMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  // do stuff
}
```

My global CORS policy seems to override the route policy, but only on the options method, I think. I'm trying to come up with a way to make both of these CORS policies play nicely. I have also tried the following, but this doesn't work either. Whichever one I put first seems to override the other one.

```
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://example.com', credentials: true }))
```

Comment: The cors middleware [by default sets up a global `OPTIONS` handler](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/v2.8.5/lib/index.js#L163). Are you saying you want to disable that for some routes?

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the `app.use()` where I'm setting a specific origin, is that making all options requests require that origin? If so, then yes, I need to disable that for specific routes and allow all origins for options requests.

Comment: _"is that making all options requests require that origin?"_ yes, for all cross-origin requests. The request method doesn't really come into it though

Comment: `app.use()` covers all types of requests including GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE etc.

Comment: I can't really tell what problem you're asking for help with here.  If you have this `app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://example.com', credentials: true }))` specified before all your routes, then it will go into action first and, if it's configured to just handle a pre-flight request for you automatically, then it will just handle it and no other routes will get a chance to look at it.  Express routes and middleware are processed in the order they are declared.

Comment: I think where I'm getting tripped up is on one hand I'm using an Authorization header to pass an API key. I guess Authorization header only gets passed when credentials are set to true, but on the other hand, I need to accept that header from all origins, since it's just an API key. :/

Comment: So, shouldn't the client just set `withCredentials: true` when adding the Authorization custom header and sending the request?

Comment: See my self-answer below. The app level cors policy wasn't allowing me to set cors policies on any other options requests. You have to set a kind of obscure and poorly documented `preflightContinue` property to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason my 2nd code snippet above wasn't working as expected was because I needed to add the `preflightContinue` property when setting the cors policy at the app level. Otherwise it will ignore cors policies on options routes set at the route level. Kind of a poorly documented thing.

The final solution was to do this at the app level:

```
app.use(cors({ 
  origin: 'https://example.com', 
  credentials: true,
  preflightContinue: true,
}))
```

Now this cors policy on the options route actually works:

```
router.options('/someroute', cors())
router.get('/someroute', cors(), someOtherMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  // do stuff
}
```

Ugh, spent so long figuring this one out. Hope this saves someone some time.